# include(): Failed opening 'includes/connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

i m having these 2 errors .i have checked for pear in xampp..it is only in license

> 1.Warning: include(includes/connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\malala\includes\new_posts.php on line 46
>
> 2.Warning: include(): Failed opening 'includes/connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\malala\includes\new_posts.php on line 46

how could i solve this issue

Comment: Do you have the directory 'malala\includes\' inside yout htdocs? If yes, do you have the file new_posts.php iside?

Comment: Can you change new_posts.php line 46 from include(includes/connect.php) to include(connect.php)?

Comment: yes i have malala/includes in my htdocs

Comment: it doesn't works   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\malala\includes\connect.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\malala\includes\new_posts.php(46): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\malala\includes\connect.php on line 2                  this error is generated by changing (includes/connect.php) to include(connect.php)